# Changing value of an object parameter in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have a code that I repeat on every Rest Service like this:

```
user = getUserByToken(request.getToken());
if (user == null) {
    response = this.buidResponse(Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED));
}else{
    do things...
} 
return response;
```

I want to create a method to avoid repeating the first 4 lines, something like:

```
bool validateUser(String token, User userOut, Response responseOut){
    userOut = getUserByToken(token);
    if (userOut == null) {
        responseOut = this.buidResponse(Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
```

}

But as in Java parameters are passed by value-ref, the parameters does not maintain its values outside the method...

What alternative do I have?

Comment: `responseOut` is a local variable, like all method arguments. Java does not have a concept of out parameters.

Comment: The easiest way to get around this is to pass a container (such as an array) as your parameter, and modify the contents of the container. But in this case you could just return the response from your method, instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a wrapper class MyDTO and keep the parameteres as fields.
Please refer below code:

```
  class MyDTO{
      String token;
      User userOut;
      Response responseOut;

    public String getToken() {
      return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
      this.token = token;
    }

    public String getUserOut() {
      return userOut;
    }

    public void setUserOut(String userOut) {
      this.userOut = userOut;
    }

    public Response getResponseOut() {
      return responseOut;
    }

    public void setResponseOut(Response responseOut) {
      this.responseOut = responseOut;
    }
  }

bool validateUser(MyDTO dto){
    dto.setUserOut(getUserByToken(dto.getToken()));
    if (dto.getUserOut() == null) {
        dto.setResponseOut(this.buidResponse(Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that option but as I need to use both User & Response in other parts of the methods, I think this option doesn't make the code cleaner/quicker. Thanks anyway as it is a valid way to do it